# SQL server inserting lots of data from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, insert

I have this application, where there is a parent child table, and customers can order products. The whole structure is quite complex to post here but suffice to say, there is one `Order` table and one `OrderDetails` table for storing the orders. Currently what we are doing is `INSERT` one record in `Order` table, and then for each item the customer added, insert each item in a loop to `OrderDetails` table. The solution is not scalable for obvious reasons. It works fine for 100 or so items, but if user goes over 1000 items, or 1000 qty of a item or so, one can start to notice the unresponsiveness of the application.

There are a couple of solutions that come to mind, but I am not sure which one would scale well. One is I use `BulkInsert` from my `asp.net` application to insert into the `OrderDetails` table. Second is I generate `XML` and then pass that to a `sql proc` and extract / insert data into `OrderDetails` table from that `XML`, but that have associate overhead of memory consumption of the `XML` generated. I know I could benchmark and see for myself what would suit best for my application, but I would like to know what is the most common strategy and would scale better when compared to other. Also, if there is another technique that I could use instead of these two, that would be better performance wise ( I know performance is subjective word, but let me narrow it down to speed ) I could use that. Which is generally used the most? What do you use in your application?

Comment: You might need to look at [Using SQL Bulk Insert with the .NET Framework](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2013/03/01/effective-use-of-sql-bulk-insert.aspx), [Dealing with huge amount of data when inserting into sql database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16891137/dealing-with-huge-amount-of-data-when-inserting-into-sql-database)

Comment: Either you misunderstand your requirements or you haven't explained yourself properly. Use BulkInsert when loading data from a RAW source such as a formatted/delimited file or source. Give us more important info to work with...some code, order count, average detail count per order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider exploring the option of using a table valued parameter in the database. You will have to create a table type object, whose structure will mimic that of the OrderDetails table. The stored proc for inserting the data will accept an input parameter of this type (such parameters are always READONLY).

In your server side code, you can construct a DataTable object containing all the Order Details data, which will be mapped to the input parameter of the stored proc. Ensure that the order of columns in the DataTable object exactly matches the order in the table valued parameter. Upon executing the query, all the data will be inserted in one shot. This will save you from looping for each row of data that is there, and will also prevent the overhead of XML parsing. This approach though will involve passing an entire object over the network.

You can read more about it here : [MSDN Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

1000 items for an order does seem quite excessive!

Would it be feasible to introduce a limit of 100 items per order into the business logic of the application?